# How to apply an accumulative aggregation function with a group by on Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1','A0', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1', 'A0', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1'],
                        'B': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                        'C': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                        'i': [1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]},
                      )

     A   B   C  i
0   A0   1   0  1
1   A0   2   1  1
2   A1   3   2  1
3   A1   3   3  1
4   A0   4   4  2
5   A0   5   5  2
6   A1   6   6  2
7   A1   7   7  2
8   A0   8   8  3
9   A0   9   9  3
10  A1  10  10  3
11  A1  11  11  3
```

I wanted to group by `A` and `i` :

```
df1.set_index(['A', 'i'], inplace=True)
df1.groupby(df1.index).sum()

          B   C
(A0, 1)   3   1
(A0, 2)   9   9
(A0, 3)  17  17
(A1, 1)   6   5
(A1, 2)  13  13
(A1, 3)  21  21
```

But I want the result of `(A0,2)` to be the sum of `(A0,1)` and `(A0,2)`, and the `(A0,3)` to be the sum of `(A0,1)`, `(A0,2)` and `(A0,3)` and the same with `A1`, I know that I can do it with a loop but I'm searching for a better solution since my DataFrame is larger than this one. The result table that I want is this

```
          B   C
(A0, 1)   3   1
(A0, 2)  12  10
(A0, 3)  29  27
(A1, 1)   6   5
(A1, 2)  19  18
(A1, 3)  40  39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [`Groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) without `df1.set_index(['A', 'i'], inplace=True)`**:

```
new_df = df1.groupby(['A','i']).sum().groupby(level = 0).cumsum()
#not need set_index
#df1.set_index(['A','i']).groupby(['A','i']).sum().groupby(level = 
new_df.index = [*new_df.index] #for expected output
print(new_df)
          B   C
(A0, 1)   3   1
(A0, 2)  12  10
(A0, 3)  29  27
(A1, 1)   6   5
(A1, 2)  19  18
(A1, 3)  40  39
```

Comment: How could I do the same with a self-made aggregation function? I mean the case where the aggregation function isn't the sum

Comment: It depends on the specific case, can you ask a new question? I'll be happy to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935748/accumulative-custom-function-with-group-by-pandas thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Summary:
 use the groupby function and aggregate sum for columns B and C. next step - groupby a second time, with just column A, and aggregate cumulative sum for columns B and C. An aggregation reduces the groupby values to a single point. Grouping with just column A removes the restriction and allows for the cumulation to get the desired result.

```
 (df1.groupby(['A','i'])
.agg({'B':'sum','C':'sum'})
.groupby(['A'])['B','C'].agg('cumsum'))

            B   C
  A i       
 A0 1   3   1
    2   12  10
    3   29  27
A1  1   6   5
    2   19  18
    3   40  39
```

Comment: he doesn't need select columns, but okey, if you want select columns... why  `(df1.groupby(['A','i'])
.agg({'B':'sum','C':'sum'}))` instead `df1.groupby(['A','i'])['B','C'].sum()`?, why `.agg('cumsum')` instead `.cumsum`?

Comment: I think I get your point. compactness. Thanks for the observation.